# Reset ajax data when button clcik using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have scenario form like this
if option selected it will come out a new field i named "hah" i call it using ajax script like this

```js
$('#bahan').change(function() {
  var id = $('#bahan').val()
  var datana = 'id=' + id
  var urlna = "<?=base_url()?>controller/food/getdetailstok";
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: urlna,
    data: datana,
    success: function(data) {
      $('#hah').html(data);
    }
  })
  return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control select2" name="bahan" id="bahan">
      <option value="">-- Choose One --</option>
      <option value="1"> 1 </option>
            <option value="2"> 2 </option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="hah"></div>
```

How to reset "hah" if i click button save. hah in reset because the value field options again become null

Comment: what is `takara` element?

Comment: I've edited my question

Comment: `$('#hah').html("");`

Comment: not work because when the option value in select hah would take the id of the selected option value. 
I've tried using a function hide() but when option value in select onclick function does not work

Answer (score 0):

$('#hah').empty() will do the trick.

.empty() will remove every element from the DOM. In your case every element in your #hah div.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('#bahan').change(function() {
     $('#hah').html("");
      var id = $('#bahan').val()
      var datana = 'id=' + id
      var urlna = "<?=base_url()?>controller/food/getdetailstok";
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: urlna,
        data: datana,
        success: function(data) {
          $('#hah').html(data);
        }
      })
      return false;
    })
```